# How can I repair soil gas barrier membrane when relocating basement drains?

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain, renovation, radon

My dad and I are finishing his basement and the three piece bathroom is roughed in by the builder. The drains for the toilet and shower are not ideally placed, so we want to move them a few inches, which means breaking up the concrete.

Because the Ontario Building Code requires a soil gas control system, and because I believe the method used in our basement is a soil gas barrier in the form of a polyethylene membrane between the gravel base and the concrete, I'm wondering what to do when the poly becomes damaged as the slab is broken. I know the continuity of the membrane is important, but I can't imagine how to tie-into the existing poly with a patch because the edges will be inaccessible.

Because I can't find any information on how renovators deal with this problem of patching the radon control barrier in the process of relocating basement drains, I wonder if it's typically just left damaged? The thing is, we got a permit, so everything is going to be inspected. (And of course, we don't want to poison ourselves or future occupants.)